# render view in new tab yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I am trying to render view in new tab
this is what I have tried

```
$this->render('receipt', array(
            'data' => $data
        ));
```

But I want to open this receipt view in new tab.
Please some one help me

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a new browser tab, this question is not about yii at all. It's a html question. If you mean something different, update your question.
You can open a new browser tab to your `receipt` controller/action with a anchor tag on your page and use the target attribute, for example: `<a href="/order/receipt" target="_blank">View receipt</a>`. Then a new browser tab wil open and yii will route `order/receipt` the url to your controller and view that renders it.
Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target